# Equilibrium carrier distribution appropriate to local temperature

Tags: statistical-mechanics, solid-state-physics, boltzmann-equation

In Chapter 13 of Ashcroft and Mermin there is a general discussion about the nonequilibrium distribution function under the relaxation time/semiclassical transport assumptions. One of the key axioms given is pictured below. In words, if the nonequilibrium distribution function has the particular form of the FD distribution (with locally varying parameters) then collisions will not alter this.

Now what I do not follow is how one determines these local parameters. Suppose I have some arbitrary distribution, $g_n(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{k},t)$. In subsequent calculations I will find it necessary to know the corresponding local temperature $T(\mathbf{r})$ and local chemical potential $\mu(\mathbf{r})$. But does this axiom not further assume that systems of interest will have some well-defined $T(\mathbf{r})$ and $\mu(\mathbf{r})$? Is this assumption general? Just to confirm and so that I'm sure I understand, if I have some general $g_n(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{k},t)$ and I want to know the corresponding $g^0_n(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{k},t)$, would I for example take $T(\mathbf{r})$ as the temperature observed at $\mathbf{r}$ even though this is not an equilibrium situation?

As an aside, why don't we allow the local parameters to depend on $t$?

[image]

Comment: What is assumed here is *local equilibrium*, where a volume around any point $\mathbf{r}$ can be considered as in thermal equilibrium, with some temperature, chemical potential, etc.

Comment: And the first sentence points out the assumption that a T can be defined locally.

Comment: @JonCuster As far as I can tell, no it does not. It says that *if* we have local equilibrium, then it is unchanged under collisions. But in the subsequent derivation of the form of an arbitrary non-equilibrium distribution function we still seem to use the notion of a local equilibrium distribution function corresponding to the non-equilibrium situation at the given point in phase space and at the given instant of time.

Comment: @RogerVadim Please see my comment above. I'm not sure if you have A&M, but I don't think you are correct. The derivation here that uses these axioms is for general nonequilibrium situations, not even local equilibrium. It seems though that a notion of a *corresponding* local equilibrium is used, in the sense I try to make clear in the comment above.

Comment: I am not going to argue about what *local equilibrium* exactly means, but the procedure is rather standard in kinetic equation theory. I could suggest [these notes](http://www.unm.edu/%7Eaierides/505/bbgky3.pdf).